# target records within Journey from random split

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a 50% random split in a Journey and I want to do some analysis on the two branches. The problem is that the email name is the same so not sure how do I pull the data for the two branches if email name is the same. Is there another criteria that I can use to select only the records from the 1st branch and the records on the second branch?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the sends, then check on the basis of external key, which will be different even if the email name is same.

You can find the external key here:

[image]

Use this query:

```
SELECT j.journeyname,
       Cast(s.eventdate AS DATE) AS 'Date',
       ja.activityname           AS 'EmailName',
       ja.activityexternalkey,
    s. SubscriberKey
FROM   [_sent] AS s
       INNER JOIN [_journeyactivity] AS ja
               ON s.triggerersenddefinitionobjectid = ja.journeyactivityobjectid
       INNER JOIN [_journey] AS j
               ON ja.versionid = j.versionid
       INNER JOIN [_subscribers] AS su
               ON s.subscriberid = su.subscriberid
where TriggeredSendCustomerKey  = 'yourcustomerkey'
```